# Adjust margin of html card element within Text RTE component in AEM

Tags: html, css, aem, aem-6

I have made use of the Text RTE component to create cards to be placed within my webpage. Using the double-headed arrow (resize) tool, I have managed to resize and place three cards in the same row.

Is it possible to add margin-left and margin-right to the html style inline tag to set the margin? It keeps getting removed after exiting the code editor in the Text RTE editor dialog.

I would greatly appreciate any form of help or sharing of knowledge if you have encountered the following issue previously. Thank you!

The following is the code to create these cards in the Text RTE component:

```
<div class="card" style="margin-left:0.5rem; margin-right: 0.5 rem; (Unable to set the margin property here, keeps getting removed)"><div class="card-header bg-transparent"><b><img src="/somepath/image.png" alt="">Document Name</b></div>
<div class="card-body"><br>
<br>
<p>Document Description</p>
<br>
<br>
<p>Document Date: 01/01/1990<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Text RTE component]

Answer (score 1):

You can add css code:

```
<style>
.card {
  margin-left:0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5 rem;
}
</style>
```

Or you can code blank card between cards:

```
<style>
.blankCard {
  float: left;
  width: 1rem;
}
</style>

    <div class="card"><div class="card-header bg-transparent"><b><img src="/somepath/image.png" alt="">Document Name</b></div>
    <div class="card-body"><br>
    <br>
    <p>Document Description</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Document Date: 01/01/1990<br>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="blankCard">
</div>

    <div class="card"><div class="card-header bg-transparent"><b><img src="/somepath/image.png" alt="">Document Name</b></div>
    <div class="card-body"><br>
    <br>
    <p>Document Description</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Document Date: 01/01/1990<br>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```